# How can i get the SUM of quantity based on Product Code and the seller selling it

Tags: sql

I have this table which is showing seller id and name with the product code and the quantity the seller sold. I want to sum up the quantity based on product id. I tried GROUP BY product_code but it sums up the quantity of every same product_code regardless of seller_id.

[image: 1]

So As a result of this picture the result of quantity for seller 200000 should be 5 and for seller 200001 quantity should be 1.

Comment: Also sqlite and oracle are two different databases , remove unrelated database tag

Comment: Also please provide desired output

Comment: Make it easy, and possible, to assist you: [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to group by seller_id

```
select
    seller_id,
     product_code,
    sum(quantity)
from
    yourtable
group by seller_id,product_code
```

Comment: I tried it but it also groups the seller in one row which i don't want because the same seller is also selling other different products. i want the sum for every product the seller is selling based on product_code.

Comment: @AhmadLeo then you just want to group by seller_id , se updated asnwer

Comment: suppose seller_1 is selling product_ 1 (quantity=3) again product_1(quantity =2) and product_2(quantity =  1) and then another seller which is seller_2 is selling product_1(quantity = 1) and product_2(quantity = 3). Here i wan to sum up quantity of each product according to the seller. So the expected result should be (after sum) seller_1 selling product_1(quantity=5) and product_2(quantity=1) and similar seller_2 is selling product_1(quantity = 1) and product_2(quantity = 3). Hope it is making sense.

Comment: @AhmadLeo then my first answer was correct

Comment: I tried your first answer but it was adding all the product having same product_code in one row. But the result i want is to sum the repeated products of every seller.

Comment: no , it doesn't, it sums up quantity of same products for each seller , I rolled back to my first answer , try it out

Comment: Thankyou its working. Sorry i was swapping seller id with product id that's why it was not working but now it is.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the seller wise sum of quantity for each product you need to use both product_code and seller_id in group by clause as below:

```
select product_code, seller_id, sum(quantity) 
from yourtable
group by product_code, seller_id
```